# Logical Replication: Schema does not exist while subscription

Tags: postgresql, replication

PostgreSQL logical replication.

I am trying to replicate the tables from server 1 to server 2.

#### In Server 1

```
create publication locale for table code.locale_cd;
CREATE PUBLICATION
```

#### In Server 2

```
create subscription indsolv_dev10 connection
    'host=192.168.0.26 port=5432 password=****** user=replicator
    dbname=indsolv_dev' publication locale;
```

Throws an error schema "code" does not exist but it's present in the database.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right host/database?

Comment: Yep. Host, port, and database are correct

Comment: "code" is present in both databases or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the database where Subscription is required.

```
\connect indsolv_dev
```

Comment: Could you flesh this out just a little? Where should the user do this? Could you rewrite the OP code as an answer?